# Recognizing foreign key in MySQL script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, create-table

I am analyzing a SQL script to find all the primary and foreign keys. I don't know whether the last line of the script "KEY `ID_STAFF` (`id_staff`)" is a primary key or a foreign key. The full script is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `conge` ( 
`id_conge` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_staff` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`annee` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`total_conge` double DEFAULT NULL,
`report_conge` double DEFAULT NULL,
`conge_pris` double DEFAULT NULL,
`debut` date DEFAULT NULL,
`fin` date DEFAULT NULL,
`conge_reste` double DEFAULT NULL,
`codeterrain` varchar(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`typeconge` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`commentaire` text,
`id_contrat` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`typeautre` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`lienbulletin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`codeterrain`,`id_conge`),
 KEY `ID_STAFF` (`id_staff`)
)
```

Comment: `KEY ID_STAFF(id_staff)` is just a normal index or a Secondary index assuming InnoDB engine

Comment: Foreign key constraints have attributes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure they were indexes.